# Enum.valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name) question

Tags: java, generics, reflection, enums

I am trying to get around a compile error ("Bound mismatch: ...") relating to dynamic enum lookup.

Basically I want to achieve something like this:

```
String enumName = whatever.getEnumName();
Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass = whatever.getEnumClass();
Enum<?> enumValue = Enum.valueOf(enumClass, enumName);
```

Whatever I do, I always end up with that compile error. Honestly, generics and enums are quite mindboggling to me...

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think it won't work exactly like this unless you have access to a type variable (through either a type or method signature). The problem is the method signature of `Enum.valueOf`:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(
    Class<T> enumType,
    String name
);
```

There's no way to get a T without a type variable. But you can do it like this if you're willing to suppress some compiler warnings:

```
public enum King{
    ELVIS
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public static void main(final String[] args){
    final Class<? extends Enum> enumType = King.class;
    final Enum<?> theOneAndOnly = Enum.valueOf(enumType, "ELVIS");
    System.out.println(theOneAndOnly.name());
}
```

**Output:**

> ELVIS

Comment: The question is about enums, generics and reflection. If you ignore generics, what's the point? Particularly going for "rare types" like `Class<? extends Enum>`.

Comment: The point is that a) it can't work otherwise without a helper method or type and b) we know for sure that any `Class<? extends Enum>` will also satisfy `Class<E extends Enum<E>>` (because that's the way enum classes work) even though there is no way to check that without a type variable. `@SuppressWarnings` is an annotation you should only use if you know what you are doing, and I do know.

Answer (score 27):

The problem is with `Class<? extends Enum<?>>`. We want `E extends Enum<E>`, but we can't get that because we have two distinct wildcards.

So we need to introduce a generic parameter, possible introduced by calling a method:

```
enum MyEnum {
    ME;
}

public class EnName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Enum<?> value = of(MyEnum.class, "ME");
        System.err.println(value);
    }
    private static <E extends Enum<E>> E of(Class<E> clazz, String name) {
        E value = Enum.valueOf(clazz, name);
        return value;
    }
}
```

But reflection is mucky and very rarely what you want. Don't do it.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, it helped a lot to further understand whats going on. Since in my particular use case I don't have anything to provide as the generic parameter, I will go for seanizer's answer.

Answer (score 7):

There's actually an alternate approach: you can use `Class.getEnumConstants` and roll your own implementation of `Enum.valueOf` that doesn't have the same type problems.  The downside is you get back a generic `Enum<?>` - but if you knew what type you had coming in, you would be able to use `Enum.valueOf` anyway.

```
private static Enum<?> findEnumValue(Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumType, String value) {
    return Arrays.stream(enumType.getEnumConstants())
                 .filter(e -> e.name().equals(value))
                 .findFirst()
                 .orElse(null);
}
```

(Note that my version returns `null` if there's no such constant rather than throwing an `IllegalArgumentException`, but that's a trivial thing to change.

Answer (score -1):

Thx @Sbodd for the answer. I took this example, added the exception we know from the standard anEnum.valueOf("ELVIS") and changed the generic method args in a way that we can use it like this:

```
       King king = findEnumValue(King.class, "ELVIS");
       System.out.println(String.valueOf(king));
```

Method:

```
/**
 * Returns the {@link Enum} for the given {@link Enum#name()} String of the given enum type. 
 * <p>
 * Example: 
 * <pre>
 * {@code     
      King king = findEnumValue(King.class, "ELVIS");
      System.out.println(String.valueOf(king));
 * }
 * </pre>
 * @param enumType the class of the enum, e.g. {@code King.class}. 
 * 
 * @param enumName the {@link Enum#name()}, e.g. "ELVIS". 
 * 
 * @return the enum instance or an exception. 
 * 
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the given {@code enumName} is no enum constant in the given {@code enumType}. 
 */
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T findEnumValue(Class<T> enumType, String enumName) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    T result = Arrays.stream(enumType.getEnumConstants())
                 .filter(e -> e.name().equals(enumName))
                 .findFirst()
                 .orElse(null);
    if(result == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "No enum constant " + enumType.getCanonicalName() + "." + enumName);
    }
    else
    {
        return result;
    }
}

public enum King{
    ELVIS
}
```

Comment: You just reimplemented Enum.valueOf with the exact same problem as the original method regarding the generic signature.