# How to create generic enum converter?

Tags: java, generics, enums

I want to write a generic class that can be used like `new EnumConverter(MyEnum.class);`

But hwo to I have to write that class so that it works with generic calls to `enum.values()`?

```
public class EnumConverter {
    public EnumConverter(Class<Enum<?>> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public EnumConverter convert(String text) {
        //error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type capture#1-of ? to Enum<?>
        for (Enum<?> candidate : type.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants()) {
            if (candidate.name().equalsIgnoreCase(text)) {
                return candidate;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what type is this.type; how is it declared?

Comment: Something wrong with your convert method as it should return `EnumConverter` while `candidate` is of type `Enum<?>` !!

Comment: I think it's a constructor

Comment: It's definitely not clear to me what the question is.

Comment: Nice question.  This is *related*, but different: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014117/enum-valueofclasst-enumtype-string-name-question  (Please do not read this comment as 'hey, this question is a dupe!')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your return type of method convert is wrong: Shoud be `Enum` instead of `EnumConverter`. And then you don't have to call `getDeclaringClass()` but use the `Class` you already have in type.

I would suggest an even more generic approach:

```
public static class EnumConverter<T extends Enum<T>>
{

    Class<T> type;

    public EnumConverter(Class<T> type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Enum<T> convert(String text)
    {
        for (Enum<T> candidate : type.getEnumConstants()) {
            if (candidate.name().equalsIgnoreCase(text)) {
                return candidate;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's proably what i'm looking for. But can't this be further optimized, as I would have to provide the type parameter both as generic param and as constructor argument, like `new EnumConverter(MyEnum.class);` or `new EnumConverter<MyEnum>();`?

Comment: Why is using this class any different to using `Enum.valueOf((Class<T> enumType, String name)`?

Comment: I did not know the Enum.valueOf()-method when writing this answer, just wanted to show how to get his approach working. Maybe you can use it to keep track of conversions ;-)

Comment: @membersound it can be further optimized by converting within a generic static method. But then you can directly use Enum.valueOf().

Answer (score 5):

your question is inconsistent and not valid code:
1) this.type is not defined as a field
2) you define convert to return `EnumConverter` but return an `Enum`

to return a enum value of an enum from text you do not need generic stuff. you simply use:

```
Enum.valueOf(MyEnum.class, "TWO")
```

Answer (score 2):

Putting together the two best answers, you get a clean one liner:

```
public <T extends Enum<T>> T getEnumValue(Class<T> type, String str) {
    return Enum.valueOf(type, str);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this if the type is not known at compile time? e.g. `Class<?> type`

Answer (score 0):

Following is not a class like requested, but still an improvement over some other answers because it produces no warnings (java 11/IDEA 2020)

```
    static <Dest extends Enum<Dest>> Dest
    convertEnumStrict(final Class<Dest> destinationClassType, final Enum<?> sourceEnum) {
        if (sourceEnum == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return Dest.valueOf(destinationClassType, sourceEnum.name());
    }

    static <Dest extends Enum<Dest>> Dest
    convertEnumOrNull(final Class<Dest> destinationClassType, final Enum<?> sourceEnum) {
        try {
            return convertEnumStrict(destinationClassType, sourceEnum);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In case if some looking for alternative solution with out for loop.

```
   // classType is target Enum
     public static Enum<?> toEnum(final Class<? extends Enum> classType, final Enum<?> enumObj) {
            if (enumObj == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return enumObj.valueOf(classType, enumObj + "");
            }
```

Usage:

```
 TestEnum1 enum1 = (TestEnum1) toEnum(TestEnum1.class, TestEnum1.HELLO_ENUM);
```