# How do I apply Enum.valueOf(type, name) after checking type.isEnum()?

Tags: java, generics, enums

```
static <T> T parse(Class<T> type, String value) {
    if (type.isEnum()) {
        return Enum.valueOf(type, value);
    }
    return null; // unimplemented
}
```

This doesn't work, because

> The method valueOf(Class<T extends Enum>, String) in the type Enum
> is not applicable for the arguments (Class, String).

How do I get around this?

Comment: Cast it to an enum class?

Comment: Try `return Enum.valueOf( (Class<? extends Enum>) type, value);`.   (From https://stackoverflow.com/a/4014381/681444 )

Comment: @racraman Thanks, it works with casting to T before returning, and applying `@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })` to the method to get rid of warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
static <T> T parse(Class<T> type, String value) {
    if (type.isEnum()) {
        return (T) Enum.valueOf((Class<? extends Enum>) type, value);
    }
    return null; // unimplemented
}
```